# Use local image after publishing Chatbot

Tags: c#, file, azure, url, botframework

I am creating hero cards that use local images, and I got them working when using the emulator locally, but can't get it working after publishing to azure. I'm trying to turn the image to base64 to use it.

```
List<CardImage> cardImages = new List<CardImage>
{
  new CardImage(url: ImageToBase64(thisService.Type.ToString()))
};

(...)

HeroCard plCard = new HeroCard()
{
  Title = $"{titles[thisService.Type.ToString()]}",
  Subtitle = $"Serviço {thisService.Frequency.ToString()} agendado para {thisService.Date.ToLongDateString()} às {thisService.Date.ToShortTimeString()}.",
  Images = cardImages,
  Buttons = cardButtons
};

(...)

public static string ImageToBase64(string imageName)
{
  var path = HostingEnvironment.MapPath($"/Resources/Images/{imageName}.PNG");
  Byte[] bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(path);
  string base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);
  return "data:image/png;base64," + base64String;
}
```

The error that appears on the channel on azure portal is the following:

```
{"error":{"message":"(#100) name_placeholder[elements][0][image_url] should represent a valid URL","type":"OAuthException","code":100,"fbtrace_id":"BLoacoRFVy7"}}
```

Is this possible to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to use the Facebook channel, which only supports hosted images. If you're on Azure, you could use blobstorage to host your images and use this public link for your image. However any hosted image will work.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I did and it worked perfectly, thanks!